# How to have a border around highlighted countries but no change in fill color in a highmaps map?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Let's say I have this map:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/plotoptions/series-border/

With this code:

```
  $(function () {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Initiate the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

            title : {
                text : 'Map border options'
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                max: 1000,
                type: 'logarithmic'
            },

            series : [{
                data : data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                name: 'Population density',
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 0.2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '/km²'
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

You can see that countries get a border if the mouse hovers over them as well as change their color to cyan.

How can I stop the color of the countries from changing on hover? I want the countries to be highlighted via the border but keep their data fill.

Is there a way to bring the country on top (like setting a z-index)? Some of my countries have an overlap and parts of the border get hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the color param as empty object, in the plotOptions.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover:{
            color: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9010nhxk/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)